# Как в битрикс переместить стили в футер?

Tags: php, битрикс

Как переместить стили и скрипты в футер из head?
Эти настройки модуля только ломают вёрстку, т.е. если установить активными галочки 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S.
в файле header.php подключение стилей и скриптов такое:

```
Asset::getInstance()->addCss(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/css/index.css");
Asset::getInstance()->addCss(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/css/jquery.fancybox.css");
Asset::getInstance()->addJs(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/js/initialScale.js");
Asset::getInstance()->addJs(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/js/plugins/device.min.js");
Asset::getInstance()->addJs(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/js/plugins/jquery-1.12.0.min.js");
Asset::getInstance()->addJs(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/js/plugins/enquire.min.js");
...
```

только на сайте намного больше стилей и скриптов, которые есть только в header.php. Наверно подключение есть ещё где-то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно проверить на всем сайте, правильно ли подключаются `css` и `js`, то есть, подключаются ли стили через `$APPLICATION->SetAdditionalCss` или его аналогов (d7), так же в компонентах посмотреть подключаются ли все файлы через

```
$this->addExternalCss("styles.css")
```

или

```
$this->addExternalJS("js.js")
```

Избавиться от прямых подключений через `html`.

Вот после всех этих правок, ставишь галочки о переносе вниз и все должно заработать.

Comment: обновил вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: если есть тестовая среда, поставь галочки и посмотри какой стиль не грузится (через консоль разработчика сможешь быстро понять проблему), все стили лежат на `index.css`? а еще, cdn случаем не включен? может проблемы как то связаны (последнее предположение довольно глупое, но с Битриксом всякое бывает:) )

Comment: такое подключение вообще правильное
 `Asset::getInstance()->addCss()` ?
Да, некоторые лежат в index.css, т.е. импортируются через @import

Comment: можно ли просто из header.php перенести вышеприведённое подключение в footer.php ?

Comment: @word, нет, он все равно в хэдер поставит

Comment: а подключение правильное, вот меня смущает ваш ответ "Да, некоторые лежат", если так, значит нужно по остальным пройтись и проверить подключение стилей, где-то точно прямым html подключают

Comment: `@import "slick.css";
@import "jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css";
@import "common.css";
@import "top_slider.css";` вот содержимое index.css
не в index.css дело.   Вы говорите, что всё равно в хэдер поставит. А как сделать чтобы не поставило?

Comment: сложно так сказать, но если быстро и колхозом, то реально можно в футер переместить стили, но только без конструкции `Asset::getInstance()->addCss()`, а прямым `html`, то есть '<link href=""/>'

Comment: а как это сделать по правильному? т.е. как опустить стили вниз?

Comment: @word, прошу прощения, я перепутал стили с js ( там же js только опускается вниз, а стили объединяются в один файл и в хэдере ж подключаются

Comment: вопрос был в том, как опустить стили вниз. Вы можете подсказать? если можно также и скрипты можно перенести вниз

Comment: @word, кстати, на счет стилей, в Битриксе вряд ли нормально получится опустить вниз стили, так как если вы выбираете объединение, то он все собирает в один файл в месте с файлами ядра. Остается единственный выход, подключить внизу руками `<link>`

Comment: а если не выбирать объединение, я его и не собирался выбирать, тогда хоть можно переместить стили? Или такое делается только через <link >?

Comment: только через `link`, Битрикс к сожалению этого делать автоматом не может, вот посмотрите решение для Битрикса: https://github.com/rivetweb/rodzeta.pageoptimizeplus